# Animated TV show with futuristic vehicles used to fight monsters

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I'm asking about an animated TV show which most likely aired on Cartoon Network, but it could have been on Super RTL too.

There was a team of 4-5 people who had their personalised vehicles like near-futuristic ones, where the tires would split in two and a saw blade would come out to help the vehicle go up a cliff or something like that.  One of the vehicles had a chain I think. Their main missions were to take monsters out, that's all I know because it was like 2011-2012 at the time.

Comment: Did it look like current (at the time) animation? Or is it possible it was a re-run of an older show?

Comment: Also, where was this? You mention Super RTL, was this in Germany? You can [edit] you r question to add any additional details you remember.

Answer (score 7):

It’s older than the dates you gave but could have been a repeat, but this sounds a lot like *Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors*.

Intro:

It was first broadcast in 1985. The protagonists are a small group of (mostly) humans who drive vehicles with special abilities and weapons. I don’t recall a specific ability of saws coming out of wheels, but the intro shows one with a similar drill ability, and one of the antagonists has a saw on his vehicle, so you could be mis-remembering.

Answer (score 0):

It's a show in cartoon network called Battle Force 5

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! It would be beneficial to [edit] in some details as to _why_ you think this what the OP is looking for. See [answer] for some extra information